# Disable auto-maximizing windows in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, maximized

How to disable auto-maximizing windows in Ubuntu 18.04 without using Unity Tweak Tool.

[image]

Comment: What kind of auto-maximising? When you drag a window to the top?

Comment: @pomsky yes, how can i do that?